# merging / consolidating multiple mongodb instances to one mongodb instance

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to figure out a method to merge data from multiple mongodb instances running at various locations (Say branches) into one main mongodb instance running at a central location (Say Head Office).

What will be the best approach to achieve the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest (and maybe the only) way is to write a script that merges the two databases instances after document.

1. Get first instance from DB_B.
2. Insert it into DB_A if needed.
3. Delete it from DB_B.
4. Repeat until done.

Instead of deleting instances from source db (DB_B), you may want to just read instances in batches. This should be more performant, but slightly more difficult to code (especially if you never done such a thing).